# If ${\bf r}=(x,y,z)$ and $r=||{\bf r} || $does $\nabla . {\bf r} =0$?

Tags: vector-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVXVM.png)

If ${\bf r}=(x,y,z)$   and   $r=||{\bf r} ||   $is  $\nabla . {\bf r} =0$  ?

In terms of derivatives of fields I know that $\nabla . r$ I'm aware it should give a scalar.
But I'm unsure if it gives $0$ or $1$

I have attached the question as I don't know how to use mathsjax

Comment: Are you trying to say that $r$ is constant?

Comment: @Randall so r_ is a vector and r is a constant

Comment: All your $r$s look the same.

Comment: @Randall I'm sorry I don't know how to code them so it makes it bold. Shall I attach a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply carry out the operation of $\nabla$ on the vector ${\bf r}=(x,y,z)$ you get:
$\nabla\cdot{\bf r}=3$, $\nabla{  r}={\bf r}/r$, $\nabla\times {\bf r}={\bf 0}$

Comment: ∇⋅  is being used for the vector r (see attached image where bold r is the vector)

Comment: for ∇=/, in the question the LHS isnt bold ()

Comment: Thanks - corrected

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with the question :)